# Issues to get end DayLight Saving time

Tags: java, dst

I am trying check the DayLight Saving Time, for that I am using the US TimeZone. As DST start for US on 10 March 2013 at 2:00AM and will end on 3 November 2013 at 2:00AM. So we have to forward the clock 1 hour at 2:00AM and when it end then have to back the clock 1 hour at 2:00AM. I just wanted to check how time will be the actual time at 2:00AM when DST end. It is working fine for start of DST but for end of DST its not working. Here is the sample of code that I have tried:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
Calendar cal =Calendar.getInstance();
if (TimeZone.getDefault().useDaylightTime())
{
for(int i = 0; i< 5 ; ++i)
{
     cal.set(2013,10,03,1,57+i,60);
     long timemillis = cal.getTimeInMillis();
     setCurrentTimeInMills(timemillis);
     String formatTime = Dateformated(timemillis);
     System.out.println(formatTime);
     }
}
```

Output is like:

```
03-11-2013 01:58:00 PST
03-11-2013 01:59:00 PST
03-11-2013 02:00:00 PST
03-11-2013 02:01:00 PST
03-11-2013 02:02:00 PST
```

My Java Version :1.6.0_16. Here Datformated() is user-define function to view the time in readable format and setCurrentTime() is also user-define method to set the current time.Can Anyone help me in that why at 1:59:60AM time become 2:00AM As best of my knowledge It should be 1:00AM instead?

Comment: What are `DateUtil` and `Dateformat`?

Comment: And can you use Joda Time instead? It's a much better library...

Comment: @assylias Now you can just check the code again I have edited for better understandability

Comment: What are `setCurrentTimeInMills` and `Dateformated`? Show the code.

Comment: Try with `cal.set(2013,10,03,0,57+i,60);` (hour = 0 instead of 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below shows the timezone change from PDT to PST

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
    DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss zz");

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(2013, 10, 03, 0, 59, 59);
    System.out.println(fmt.format(cal.getTime()));

    cal.set(2013, 10, 03, 1, 0, 0);
    System.out.println(fmt.format(cal.getTime()));
}
```

outputs:

```
03-11-13 00:59:59 PDT
03-11-13 01:00:00 PST
```

Comment: thanks for your response but my doubt is that why Timezone getting changed from PDT to PST at 1:00AM, as DST ends at 2:00AM, As per my understanding there should be 1:00AM when there is 01:59:60. Can you please clear my doubt if possible.

Comment: @JackNeil I am not sure to be honest. You can maybe post a new question using my code and explaing what output you expected instead of what you actually get (and add the `date` tag to that question).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. As per your suggestion I have posted a new question, hope this may help me out :)